# Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

this is a ionic angular project that i'm working on, i'm using ng-lazyload-image plugin [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image). when i start compiling it showing errors like this.

```
Error: ./node_modules/ng-lazyload-image/fesm2015/ng-lazyload-image.mjs 401:10-19

Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Answer (score 18):

This means your bundler resolves .mjs files, however it doesn't know that they are ESM modules. On webpack, you can add the following to rules.

webpack.config.js (in project root)

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.mjs$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          type: "javascript/auto"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: I add  the file you mentionned without difference. I still got the errors

Comment: Any idea why this would have worked until last week, and now is failing to compile on a fresh build when nothing else changed?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Joosep.P works, but for someone with laravel and webpackmix the following is the way to go. In webpack.mix.js file add the following:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                type: "javascript/auto"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Just posting it as another answer as it may help someone else or me to find the solution with laravel and webpackmix easily in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Found a solution for craco.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      });
      return webpackConfig;
    },
    
    plugins: [
      // Inject the "__DEV__" global variable.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
      })
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: The "EDIT" and the previous version of this post indicate that you were looking for a solution for a different problem than described in the question at the top of this page. Even if you have found it now and have desribed it here, it is not a solution to the only relevant question on this page. Can you confirm that this is answering the question at the top? Or is this an answer to something different?

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with different Angular versions.

If ng-lazyload-image is using Angular 13 and your own project is using a lower version this will happen. There are some breaking changes since Angular 13.

If ng-lazyload-image is using Angular 13 there are no es2015 files generated for it's npm package and your compiler is still looking for them.

An option to solve this would be to use a lower version of the ng-lazyload-image package or update your own Angular to Angular 13+