# Angular 10 Upgrade - Can't import the named exports from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, carousel

We are performing Angular upgrade on a legacy application, post angular 10 upgrade and install, facing several issue of same sort when trying to start the application using 'npm start'

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 483:12-24
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 493:13-25
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 503:16-28
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 329:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 438:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel/fesm2015/ngx-slick-carousel.mjs 285:11-24
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

**Setup**:
**Node version** - 16.9.1 ,
**typescript** - 4.0.8 ,
**Angular** -10.2.5 ,
**Ngx-slick-Carousel** - **0.6.0** - suggested version for angular 10 as per official support,
tsconfig.json - target is updated from "es5" to "es2015" post upgrade of angular (adding this as suspect but reverting didn't make it work either)

P.S
no webpack.config.ts in the project to do suggested changes like in this issue as well
[Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054449/cant-import-the-named-export-directive-from-non-ecmascript-module-only-defau)

Comment: issue resolved in after Angular version 12 upgrade